# How do I make the window scroll on mousedown, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I was just wondering why this isnt working:

```
$('#down-a-bit').mousedown(function(){
    setTimeout( $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top += 1}) ,300); 
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would greatly be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) instead of setTimeout. If you use setTimeout, wrap it in a function.

http://jsfiddle.net/pMTsF/

Comment: I need it to keep scrolling while the user has a mouse key down

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you want. Do you want to scroll down as long as the user doesn't release the mouse or do you want to scroll down to a fixed point?

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/pMTsF/1/ for two variations. Remember that you have to catch the mouseup event on the body tag as #down-a-bit moves away from your cursor.